# Automapper self referencing model projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

I've got a problem handling self referencing model in my application using Automapper Projections. This is how my models look like:

```
public class Letter 
{
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}

    public Letter ParentLetter {get; set;

    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public string Content {get; set;}

    public DateTime? ReceivedTime {get; set;}

    public DateTime? SendingTime {get; set;}

    public List<Destination> Destinations {get; set;}

    public List<Letter> Responses {get; set;}
}

public class LetterView 
{
    public int? ParentId {get; set;}

    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public string Content {get; set;}

    public DateTime? ReceivedTime {get; set;}

    public DateTime? SendingTime {get; set;}

    public List<DestinationView> Destinations {get; set;}

    public List<LetterView> Responses {get; set;}
}


public class Destination 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}

    ..
}

public class DestinationView 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
}

// The mapping:

CreateMap<Destination, DestinationView>
CreateMap<Letter, LetterView>
```

My problem is with mapping Letter to LetterView. The problem is somewhere with the Responses, I just can't figure out what should be changed.

Whenever running unit tests and asserting mapping configurations everything works, as well as mapping a letter with multiple responses to a view model.
However, whenever I get a letter with it's resposnes from the database (Entity framework 6), the projection to LetterView throws a stackoverflow exception.

Can anyone please explain me why this happens only on projection? What should I change?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the stack overflow?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options here, but usually the best choice is to set a max depth on the Responses. AutoMapper will try to spider the properties, and you've got a self-referencing DTO. First try this:

```
CreateMap<Letter, LetterView>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Responses, opt => opt.MaxDepth(3));
```

Another option is to pre-wire your DTOs with a specific depth. You'd create a LetterView, and a ChildLetterView. Your ChildLetterView would not have a "Responses" property, giving you exactly 2 levels of depth on your DTO side. You can make this as deep as you want, but be very explicit in the DTO types in where they are in the hierarchy with Parent/Child/Grandchild/Greatgrandchild type names.

Comment: I want a high number of depth levels, so setting this explicity with different objects would not be good here. I tried setting the max depth - could not find it on a ForMember, only on the map itself. When setting max length I get the exception - value can not be null, parameter name: body

Comment: Also I don't know if it effects the problem but I also have a parent letter, I added it to the model described in the question

Answer (score 0):

You probably have [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456846(v=vs.100).aspx) enabled on your DbContext. Circular references may produce stack overflow exception. The best way to avoid it is to disable lazy loading :

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
// Bring entity from database then reenable lazy loading if needed
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

However, you will need to [include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) all required navigation properties since EntityFramework will not brought them back while lazy loading is deactivated. Don't forget to re enable it after if you need it for other requests.